# Display data from SQL Database in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am new in WordPress so i need to display some data from database to a WordPress php page.

I add this code inside my functions.php (inside my installed theme)

```
function ws_count_completed_courses() {
$ws_current_user = get_current_user_id();
global $wpdb;

//Count completed courses for logged user.
$ws_completed_courses = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(item_id) FROM 
$wpdb->user_items WHERE status = 'completed' AND used_id = 
$ws_current_user");
}
```

And after that inside my dashboard.php i have added the next code...

```
<p>The user has been finished <?php echo $ws_completed_courses ; ?> courses</p>
```

But i only see on website **The user has been finished courses**

Where is my mistake and how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 21-Nov-18**

**function.php**

```
function ws_count_completed_courses() {
$ws_current_user = get_current_user_id();
var_dump($ws_current_user);
global $wpdb;    

$ws_completed_courses = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT(item_id) FROM 
$wpdb->user_items WHERE status = 'completed' AND user_id = 
$ws_current_user" );

foreach ($ws_completed_courses as $course) {
$completedCourseCount = $course->user_item_id;
}
return $completedCourseCount;   
}
```

**dashboard.php**

```
<p>The user has been finished <?php echo ws_count_completed_courses(); ?> courses</p>
```

Comment: Does "get_results" return an array of fields? I think you need the first field in the results. I think you are treating it like a string.

Comment: "get_results" should return string because i use COUNT, and it should return only one number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [$wpdb tutorials](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) you could google; but, here's a conceptual overview that might help get you started:

1. From a SQL prompt, make sure your query works. Then figure out how to adapt the SQL to use program variables in your PHP code.
2. Take a look at the structure you are getting back from your query:

   `var_dump($ws_current_user);`
3. There are lots of way to extract the data from the returned structure, but the most common approach is something like this:

   `foreach ($ws_completed_courses as $course) {
       $completedCourseCount = $course->colum_you_want;
   }`
4. Return the value you extracted as the last line in your function:

   `return $completedCourseCount;`
5. Call the function like this:

   `echo ws_count_completed_courses();`

Comment: Hi ChuckC, i try with your solution but i receive int(3), i am not sure where is the problem...  i also try to test the SQL statement using another statement to count registered users... but the results is the same... My code is updated right now, could you please check the updated section and give me another instructions?

Answer (score 0):

[$wpdb->get_results](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) returns an array or an object. So try one of these:

```
echo $ws_completed_courses['COUNT(item_id)'];
echo $ws_completed_courses->COUNT(item_id);
```

EDIT: Ok, try this then:

```
function ws_count_completed_courses() {
 $ws_current_user = get_current_user_id();
 global $wpdb;    

 $ws_completed_courses = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT(item_id) as user_item_id FROM $wpdb->user_items WHERE status = 'completed' AND user_id = $ws_current_user" );

 foreach ($ws_completed_courses as $course) {
   $completedCourseCount = $course->user_item_id;
 }
return $completedCourseCount;   
}
```

Comment: They didn't work also.. could you please check the edit on my code? Thanks

Comment: Ok see above, made a small tweak to the SQL query.

Comment: Did it work changing to "SELECT COUNT(item_id) as user_item_id"